# laravel filter group routes with same name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm stuck with this annoying problem in my laravel 4 project wich has three types of users being students, teachers and moderator (I use Entrust as role management solution).

Each of them can browse the same route, but depending on the user type, another method should be called. So my route.php files was structured like this:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){


Route::group(array('before' => 'teacher'), function(){
        Route::get('/tasks',array('as'=>'tasks','uses'=>'TasksController@tasksAsTeacher'));
        Route::get('/task/{id}',array('as'=>'showTask','uses'=>'TasksController@showTaskAsTeacher'));



});
Route::group(array('before' => 'moderator'), function(){
        Route::get('/tasks',array('as'=>'tasks','uses'=>'TasksController@tasksAsModerator'));
        Route::get('/task/{id}',array('as'=>'showTask','uses'=>'TasksController@showTaskAsModerator'));

});     
Route::group(array('before' => 'student'), function(){

        Route::get('/tasks',array('as'=>'tasks','uses'=>'TasksController@tasksAsStudent'));
        Route::get('/task/{id}',array('as'=>'showTask','uses'=>'TasksController@showTaskAsStudent'));




});

});
```

However, browsing these routes with a teacher or moderator account always returned 404 errors. I found that was because the routes were redefined in the two other filter groups.

So if I would redirect a teacher user to 'showTask', laravel would return tasks as a route for students,as that's the last time the 'showTask' route was redefined, and I would get a 404 error.

My question now was: what would be the best way to handle this error?

I hope this isn't too messy. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are these filters located? This may be an Entrust problem and not an issue with laravel

Comment: @SteveBauman in app/filters.php

Answer (score 1):

Taking from @Matthias S's answer, does this work? Instead of using the entrust filter, check the permissions for the route like this:

```
//routes.php
 if(Entrust::hasRole('teacher')) {
     Route::get('/tasks',array('as'=>'tasks','uses'=>'TasksController@tasksAsTeacher'));
     Route::get('/task/{id}',array('as'=>'showTask','uses'=>'TasksController@showTaskAsTeacher'));
 }
```

Repeat for different roles

EDIT: Also if you had the role of the user stored in a session, you could use a sort of automatic route like this:

```
//routes.php
 if(Entrust::hasRole(Session::get('role'))) {
     Route::get('/tasks',array('as'=>'tasks','uses'=>'TasksController@tasksAs'.Session::get('role')));
     Route::get('/task/{id}',array('as'=>'showTask','uses'=>'TasksController@showTaskAs'.Session::get('role')));
 }
```

This way you can add as many roles as you want once you add the correct controller function for the role.

EDIT #2:

Or I guess even better

```
//routes.php - UPDATED, verify role inside controller instead of defining routes based on role
     Route::get('/tasks',array('as'=>'tasks','uses'=>'TasksController@tasks'));
     Route::get('/task/{id}',array('as'=>'showTask','uses'=>'TasksController@showTask'));


//TasksController.php
public function __construct(){
    if(!Session::get('role')){ //Make sure the user has a role assigned
        return Redirect::to('login'); // Redirect to login or permission screen if not
    }
}

public function tasks(){
    if(Entrust::hasRole(Session::get('role')){
        $tasks = Tasks::where('role_id', '=', $role->id); // Get tasks based on role
        View::make('tasks.index')->with('tasks', $tasks);
    } else{
        // Show permissions error for user
    }
}

public function showTask($task_id){
    if(Entrust::hasRole(Session::get('role')){
        $task = Tasks::where('role_id', '=', $role->id)->where('id', '=', $task_id)->first();
        View::make('tasks.view')->with('task', $task);
    }
}
```

Comment: This partially works, but the problem here is that when a user is logged out, so no if-statement is true, none of these routes are set, and I get errors for calling non-existing routes in eg the navbar

Comment: Ah yes that's true, never thought about that... I'll update my 'EDIT #2' answer

Comment: But another suggestion, shouldn't a guest user have a different view than a logged in user? IMO, a guest user shouldn't be able to see the navigation of a logged in user unless they have access to be able to view it

Comment: You're right , but it's actually a 'stupid' thing: in the navbar there's an if-statement that checks if the user is logged in or not. I f not, a login link is displayed. If yes, the routes are returned.

Comment: Have you tried using different layout files for a guest user and a logged in user? I use two layouts (one named auth.blade.php, another named main.blade.php for logged in users). I think it's a good practice since there are only two states of a user (logged off/logged in), you only have to maintain two files. This is easier to achieve if you specify your layout file in your controller rather than the view itself as shown here: http://laravel.com/docs/templates#controller-layouts

Comment: Or I could set all the routes by default with a 404 error as closure, but I guess that's too much of a hussle

Comment: More important, this causes a problem when logging in, as the route to redirect to after a succesfull login is not set

Comment: This is not the case with my edited suggestion. Your routes will be defined and you can verify their role/logged in status inside the controller rather than defining routes based on their status. On another note, if the data returned is completely different per role as you say, this should be done through separate controllers/models/routes to avoid 'spaghettification' in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Move the secondary routes group out of the main auth group, then use the pipe command to run auth before for each group e.g.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|teacher'), function(){
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|moderator'), function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your approach is a good way to get this done. I would think that defining the same routes twice is not good practice, but I have no idea if that is true.

One way to work around this could be that you define only two routes and let the controller decide which action to perform based on the role of the user. This is not a direct solution to your problem but another way of handling the issue of having different roles performing different controller actions.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){

     Route::get('/tasks',array('as'=>'tasks','uses'=>'TasksController@tasks'));
     Route::get('/task/{id}',array('as'=>'showTask','uses'=>'TasksController@showTask'));

});
```

Then in your TasksController, you make the methods tasks and showTask something like this

```
class TasksController extends BaseController {
  public function tasks() {
    if(Entrust::hasRole('teacher')) {
      return $this->tasksAsTeacher();
    } else if(Entrust::hasRole('moderator')) {
      return $this->tasksAsModerator();
    } else if(Entrust::hasRole('student')) {
      return $this->tasksAsStudent();
    }
  }

  public function showTask($id) {
    if(Entrust::hasRole('teacher')) {
      return $this->showTaskAsTeacher($id);
    } else if(Entrust::hasRole('moderator')) {
      return $this->showTaskAsModerator($id);
    } else if(Entrust::hasRole('student')) {
      return $this->showTaskAsStudent($id);
    }
  }
}
```

Just another way to do this, makes your routes cleaner and puts the logic into the controller.

Comment: I used to do this, but I'm not sure either what would be the best way to do this

Comment: @vrijdrogenaam I agree, this is definitely a work around rather then a complete solution. Checking the users role every time for every controller function would be very redundant. What if you decided to add/change/remove a user role? You'd have to go through every controller and function and modify it.

Comment: @SteveBauman Indeed, but what would be the general professional way to face this problem? I guess this passing different views depending on the user's role is a common technique in websites, isn't it?

Comment: @vrijdrogenaam I would say having the same view but passing in different data to the view depending on the role would make more sense, unless of course the data is going to be completely different on every role. If you have separate roles to control access to different data on the same tables then you should definitely use the same views, but grab the data for that specified role. Have you taken a look at my answer yet to see if that suits your needs?

Comment: I have, and it works, but I'm rather looking for the 'best' way.
The views indeed are completely different, different data is passed etc

Comment: Ahh I see, unfortunately I've never ran into that sort of project yet. Sorry I couldn't help you solve your issue!

Comment: @vrijdrogenaam I used Role-Based models mostly to represent a hierachy. In that case some roles are allowed to see more then others and I never have the same routes twice. The argument, that if the roles change you have to go through all the controllers is not really that good. If you choose filters and put it in the routes, you would have to create new filters and make new routes every time the roles change, too. Your case is quite unique. Maybe there is no real best practice for something like that.

Comment: @MatthiasS I Know. I'm really stuck on this